# CSS full height floated legend

Tags: html, css, forms, css-float

I am attempting to create a CSS stylesheet to make fieldsets less ugly.

I am trying to use a left floated `legend` (in red) with all of the radio options on the right. At present, it looks like this:

[image]

I am happy with the above, but the problem occurs when I scale down the browser window size. I would like the the height of the `label` to increase and the label text to wrap. Unfortunately the whole thing gets pushed down onto the next line (below the `legend`), like this:

[image]

I believe the solution here is to make the floated `legend` have a 100% height.

I understand that the common solution to this problem is to apply `overflow: auto` on the parent div and `height: 100%` to the floated item, but this does not seem to work here.

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<fieldset class="radioquestion">
  <legend>Sample question?: </legend>
  <div class="radioanswers">
    <div class="radioanswer">
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question1answer1" value="answer1" required="true"/>
      <label class="radiolabel">Here is a sample answer 1<label>
    </div>
    <div class="radioanswer">
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question1answer2" value="answer2" required="true"/>
      <label class="radiolabel">A second sample answer is this one. This is a long answer.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radioanswer">
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question1answer3" value="answer3" required="true"/>
      <label class="radiolabel">And a third.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```

My CSS is:

```
.radioquestion{
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

.radioquestion legend{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right; 
  background-color: red;
}

.radioanswers{
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.radioanswer label{
  width: initial;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.radioanswer{

}

input[type="radio"]{
  float: left;
  width: initial;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from `.radioanswers` and add `overflow: hidden` instead:

```
.radioanswers {
    /* float: left; */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Working example on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pdz4xrh7/)

Comment: Thanks Marvin, that worked a treat!

One follow-up question, please: If I wanted to make the wrapped label text not go below the radio button, what change should I make? i.e. radio button block to be full height.

Comment: Nevermind, worked it out by adding `display: block; overflow: hidden;` to `.radioanswer label`.

Thanks again for your help.